# What is the first instance of a Seeing Stone or Magic Mirror with multiple simultaneous connections?

Tags: magic, history-of

What is the first science fiction/fantasy world that used a seeing stone or magic mirror in a way where a message/connection is duplicated across multiple endpoints at the same time?

I know the *Lord of the Rings* Seeing Stones (Palantir) could hypothetically connect with multiple other Seeing Stones simultaneously, but in my limited memory of *The Lord of the Rings*, I don't remember that ever taking place in writing. So, that wouldn't count.  I am assuming that Tolkien drew from prior (ancient?) works in using that concept; perhaps one of them might have such an example.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're also looking for an instance where multiple connections are actually seen in-universe, rather than simply being theoretically possible. Otherwise, any work that didn't explicitly state that two devices were exclusively linked, or that only one other device could be reached at any given time, could be considered as qualifying, because there's no explicit evidence that the device *couldn't* contact multiple other devices.

Comment: @RDFozz, good question, yes, I am looking for an example of in-universe use of such technology in that way.